# How would I filter a pandas DF by count and average the groups at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there a way to efficiently filter by the number of instances in a pandas dataframe (.groupby) *and* calculate the average for said filtered group?

Lets take this example dataframe I have. `t_users` and `c_users` are paired, with the month and year the pair occurred, and a calculated column.

```
x = [
[ 1000   , 4756   , 6  , 2017 , 0.36 ],
[1000   , 2357   , 6  , 2017 , 0.42 ],
[ 1000   , 2400   , 6  , 2017 , 0.76 ],
[ 1000   , 2400   , 6  , 2017 , 1.11 ],
[ 1000   , 2400   , 6  , 2017 , 0.27 ],
[ 1000   , 2400   , 6  , 2017 , 1.57 ],
[ 2399   , 9531   , 6  , 2017 , 0.57 ],
[ 3999   , 8532   , 6  , 2017 , 0.27 ],
[ 3999   , 2138   , 6  , 2017 , 1.76] ,
[ 1039   , 4215   , 6  , 2017 , 0.26]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['t_user','c_user','mo','yr','tval'])


|    | t_user | c_user | mo | yr   | tval |
|----|--------|--------|----|------|------|
| 0  | 1000   | 4756   | 6  | 2017 | 0.36 |
| 1  | 1000   | 2357   | 6  | 2017 | 0.42 |
| 2  | 1000   | 2400   | 6  | 2017 | 0.76 |
| 3  | 1000   | 2400   | 6  | 2017 | 1.11 |
| 4  | 1000   | 2400   | 6  | 2017 | 0.27 |
| 6  | 1000   | 2400   | 6  | 2017 | 1.57 |
| 7  | 2399   | 9531   | 6  | 2017 | 0.57 |
| 8  | 3999   | 8532   | 6  | 2017 | 0.27 |
| 9  | 3999   | 2138   | 6  | 2017 | 1.76 |
| 10 | 1039   | 4215   | 6  | 2017 | 0.26 |
```

In this example, I want to group all user pairs that occur 4 times. There is only one pair that meets this (index 2 - 6, acct pair 1000 and 2400).

I know the first bit is easily achieved by

```py
df= df.groupby(['t_user', 'c_user', 'mo', 'yr']).size().reset_index(name='ct')
df = df[df['ct'] == 24].reset_index()
```

At the same time, I would like to average the `tval` column for that pair over those 4 rows. I dont need any of the other data. Where does that happen?

Ideally the result would be applied to a greater dataset, returning all rows that met the number requirement, looking something like:

```
| t_user | c_user | mo | yr   | tval_avg |
|--------|--------|----|------|----------|
| 1000   | 2400   | 6  | 2017 |   0.93   |
```

I tried a `df.groupby().size()` and joined it with with `df.groupby.mean()` but it was very messy and didn't work right. I think I might be missing something simple here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `groupby` + `transform` to calculate, filter and apply the average.

`transform` will keep the original structure (and just repeat values), so you can use it to filter on the same slicing function.

On example below:

```py
gpd = df[
    df.groupby(['t_user', 'c_user', 'mo', 'yr']).transform('count').values >= 4 #filter by greater than 3
].groupby(['t_user', 'c_user', 'mo', 'yr']).agg({'tval': 'mean'}).reset_index() ## aggregate result

gpd
Out[1]:
    t_user  c_user  mo  yr      tval
0   1000    2400    6   2017    0.9275
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Anytime @Mac, glad to help!